# Why does write() call not display output on terminal when program is run in background via Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, terminal, background, system-calls

Here is my program `foo.c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("foo\n");
    write(0, "bar\n", 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Both `foo` and `bar` are printed on the terminal if I run the program in foreground or background.

```
$ gcc foo.c
$ ./a.out 
foo
bar
$ ./a.out &
[1] 2081
$ foo
bar

[1]+  Done                    ./a.out
```

But when I run the program via `Makefile`, I see `bar` being printed only when the program is running in foreground. It does not get printed on the terminal when the program is running in background.

Here is how my `Makefile` looks.

```
fg:
        gcc foo.c
        ./a.out
        sleep 1

bg:
        gcc foo.c
        ./a.out &
        sleep 1
```

Here is the output.

```
$ make fg
gcc foo.c
./a.out
foo
bar
sleep 1
$ make bg
gcc foo.c
./a.out &
sleep 1
foo
$
```

Why is `bar` not printed on the terminal when the program is run in background via `Makefile`?

Comment: `write(0,` You sure you are writing to `stdout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is writing to standard *input* with the `write()` system call.  It isn't guaranteed that you can do that, nor is it guaranteed that when you do, it will appear on the terminal.

Most likely, `make` is supplying `/dev/null` as the standard input, so when your program attempts to write to it, it either fails (not open for writing) or succeeds in writing to the black hole.

When I revise the code in `foo.c` to read:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (printf("foo\n") != 4)
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write 4 bytes to standard output\n");
    if (write(0, "bar\n", 4) != 4)
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write 4 bytes to standard input\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and then run it with `make bg`, then I get:

```
$ make bg
gcc foo.c
./a.out &
sleep 1
Failed to write 4 bytes to standard input
foo
$
```

Comment: Indeed, that was the mistake in my program. If I fix `write(0` to `write(1`, the issue is resolved. Now I see both `foo` and `bar` being printed with `make bg`. Thanks!